# Emacs: Key binding: How to move point to the end of a string

Tags: emacs

Is there a key binding to move the point to end of the next string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If point is at the beginning of the string, you can use `C-M-f` to move past the end:

```
 "this is my string"
↑ from here         ↑ to here
```

However, this doesn't work if point is inside the string. `C-s "` might be the simplest way.

Answer (score 2):

Most programming modes will define a syntax class for delimiters of string literals.  You can use `skip-syntax-forward` to move to these.  I don't know exactly the behavior you want, but this is the key to finding where string delimiters are.

```
(skip-syntax-forward "^\"")
```

- http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Motion-and-Syntax.html
- http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Syntax-Class-Table.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, at least a couple of them. `C-u 2 C-e` or `C-n C-e` come to mind.

Answer (score 0):

`(move-end-of-line 2)` is the function.

If you want, you can bind it to a key with:

`(global-set-key [f8] '(lambda () (interactive)(move-end-of-line 2)))`

Here you bind it to f8. But yea, most logically you would use `C-n C-e`